# How can I insert ingest node IP in painless script using ingestion pipeline in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I want to insert the ingest node IP by default using a painless script. Or is there any other way to insert the elastic search machines IP into the documents automatically?

Comment: I'm curious why you need to do this? Can you explain your use case in more details?

Comment: @Val, In a cluster I will be having different ingest nodes, and I need to know through which node the document is getting inserted for future analytics and diagnostics

Comment: Is it important to know that at the document level or is it sufficient to know at the cluster level how many documents each ingest node has processed?

Comment: need it in the document level

Comment: Ok, then there's no way that I know of to get that information from within the ingest pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that I know of to get that information form within an ingest pipeline.

If you need to know at the cluster level, how many documents each ingest node has processed, you can find that out using the following call.

```
GET _nodes/stats?filter_path=**.ingest
```

In the response, you'll get the stats of each ingest pipeline and how many documents each of their processors have processed.